# is there better or correct way to use objects with vector in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, vector

i have a class like this:

```
class Foo{
public:
   Foo(); 
   Foo(int, int, int)
  ~Foo();
private:    
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
}
```

and int main function and like to save my elements(objects) in a vector:

```
int main()
{
   vector <Foo*> foo; // <------this line
   for(int i=0; i<=500; i++){
   foo.push_back(new Foo(i+1,i+2; i+3)); //<------ this line 
}
```

is there a better solution to do that and replace 2 line above?

tnx all;

Comment: Why are you using a pointer in the vector?

Comment: Just use `std::vector<Foo>`. Who told you you need to have a pointer?

Comment: I would avoid using a pointer and rather use a straightforward object, if possible. Having a vector of dynamically allocated objects smells pretty much like memory leak, as forgetting to free is very common. At least use smart pointers

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and BoBTFish and Sossenbinder   i am prefering to create my object in heap. is that true for 500 or more object that i use my object in statck memory??

Comment: @mehdi `std::vector` will place the objects in the "heap" anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unlearn that Java thing where you write "new" all the time just to create an object.

```
int main()
{
   vector<Foo> foo;
   for(int i=0; i<=500; i++)
       foo.push_back(Foo(i+1, i+2, i+3));
}
```

or, in C++11,

```
int main()
{
   vector<Foo> foo;
   for(int i=0; i<=500; i++)
       foo.emplace_back(i+1, i+2, i+3);
}
```

Comment: tnx, does object create in heap or statck?

Comment: @mehdi `foo` is an object with automatic storage. Its elements are in the free store. It's popular to call those "the stack" and "the heap", respectively, even though those are implementation details and don't exist in C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo: its popular because those are the most common implementations on most platforms.